# How can i filter values from the data coming from api call in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I am using react and redux to fetch data from an API call and now I have created a new variable and assigned it the same data. In the code, I am going to manipulate this new variable called filterClassifieds to display results. The issue is that is coming empty only and is not storing anything initially when the page loads and hence shows 0 results in the table. So the data is not populating from original data i.e. classifieds to filterClassifieds. Where should I modify the implementation in my react class or in redux i.e. actions/reducers?

Here's the code

classifieds.js

```
import React, { useState,useEffect,useMemo } from "react";
import './classifieds.scss'
import { OverlayBox } from "../../components/Main-Pages/overlay-box/overlay-box";
import { SideFilter } from "../../components/Main-Pages/side-filter/side-filtrer";
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import SpinnerButton from "../../components/Spinner/Spinner";
import { getClassifieds } from "../../redux/actions/classifiedsAction";

export const Classifieds = ()=>{

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const buttons = ['Show All','Rental','Services','Wanted','Cars','For Sale', 'More'];
    const moreButtons = ['Baby sitting','Beauty parlor','Fashion','Household Help'
    ,'Real Estate','Others'];

    const [active,setActive] = useState('Show All');
    const [activeMoreButtons,setActiveMoreButtons] = useState('');
    const [modal,setModal] = useState(false);

  const classifieds = useSelector((state) => state.classifieds.Classifieds);
  const classifiedsLoading = useSelector((state) => state.classifieds.loading);

  // const [filterClassifieds,setFilterClassifieds] = useState(classifieds);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   setFilterClassifieds(classifieds);
  // }, [classifieds]);

  const filterClassifieds = classifieds.filter((item) => {
    return active !== "Show All" ? item.category === active : true;
  });
  
    const handleButton = (name)=>{
        if(modal)setModal(false);
        setActiveMoreButtons('');
        setActive(name);
        // if(name==='Show All'){
        //    setFilterClassifieds(classifieds);
        // }else{
        //    let newClassifieds = classifieds.filter((itm)=>
        //   {
        //     return itm.category === name;
        //   }
        //   )
        //   setFilterClassifieds(newClassifieds);
        // }
    }

    const openModal =()=>{
        setModal(!modal);
    }

    const handleMoreButton=(name)=>{
        setActive('More');
        setModal(!modal);
        setActiveMoreButtons(name)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      const generateClassifieds = async () => {
          await dispatch(getClassifieds());
        };
        generateClassifieds();
  }, [dispatch]);


  const transformDate = (datePosted)=> {
      let newDate = new Date(datePosted);
      return newDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
  }

  // console.log(filterClassifieds);
    return(
        <div>
         <OverlayBox name={"Classifieds"}/>
             {/* <div classNameName="row">
        //         <div classNameName="col-4">
        //             <SideFilter/>
        //         </div>
        //         <div classNameName="col-8"> column</div>
        //     </div> */}
        <div className="section properties">
    <div className="container">
      <ul className="properties-filter">
          {
            buttons.map((name,index)=>{
            return name!=='More' ?(
            <li key={ index }>
            <button
                 className={active === name ? 'is_active' : ''}
                 onClick={()=>handleButton(name)}
                 >{name}</button>        
            </li>
            ):(
                <li key={ index }>
            <button
                 className={active === name ? 'is_active' : ''}
                 onClick={()=>openModal(name)}
                 >
                    {name}
                 <i className="fa fa-arrow-down-short-wide"></i>
                 </button>
                 {
                    modal?
                        <Card body className='card-design'>
                            <ul>
                            {moreButtons.map((val,index)=>
                            (
                            <li className={activeMoreButtons === val ? 'card-active card-li' : 'card-li'} key={index} onClick={()=>handleMoreButton(val)}>        
                            {val}
                            </li>
                            ))}
                            </ul>
                            </Card>:<></>
                 }        
            </li>
            )
})
          }
      </ul>
      <div className="row properties-box">
        <div className="col-9 properties-header">
            <p className="properties-text">
                Free Classifieds
            </p>
            </div>
        <div className="col-3 text-end properties-text">
        <NavLink to='/post-ad' className='col-lg-2'>Post Ad</NavLink>
        </div>
      <Table striped hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Date Posted</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
        {classifiedsLoading?<></>:
      <tbody>
        {filterClassifieds?.map((val,ind)=>(
          <tr key={ind}>
            <td>{val?.category}</td>
            <td>{val?.heading.split('', 86).reduce((o, c) => o.length === 85 ? `${o}${c}...` : `${o}${c}` , '')}</td>
            <td>{transformDate(val?.date)}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
        }
    </Table>
      </div>
      {/* <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-12">
          <ul className="pagination">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a className="is_active" href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div> */}
    </div>
  </div>

            </div>
        
    )

}
```

action.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export const GET_CLASSIFIEDS = "GET_CLASSIFIEDS";
export const CLASSIFIEDS_LOADING = "CLASSIFIEDS_LOADING";

// Get all posts
export const getClassifieds = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setClassifiedsLoading());
    axios
      .get("/posts")
      .then((res) =>
        dispatch({
          type: GET_CLASSIFIEDS,
          payload: res.data,
        })
      )
      .catch((err) =>
        dispatch({
          type: CLASSIFIEDS_LOADING,
          payload: {},
        })
      );
  };
  

  // Classifieds loading
  export const setClassifiedsLoading = () => {
    return {
      type: CLASSIFIEDS_LOADING,
    };
  };
```

reducer.js

```
import { GET_CLASSIFIEDS, CLASSIFIEDS_LOADING } from "../actions/classifiedsAction";

const initialState = {
  Classifieds: null,
  filterClassifieds: null,
  loading: true,
};

export const ClassifiedsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CLASSIFIEDS:
      return {
        ...state,
        Classifieds: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    case CLASSIFIEDS_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Edit for more clarity:
Initially both my classifieds and filterClassifieds will be empty before dispatch but after some milliseconds data will be populated in classifieds but not in filterClassifieds

Here's the screenshot of the log
[image: classifiedslogs]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe it seems like the selected `classifieds` state from Redux is updated *after* this component mounts and initializes the local `filterClassifieds` state to `null`.

First, ensure that the selected `classifieds` state maintains an array invariant to allow it to ***always*** be filterable.

```js
const initialState = {
  Classifieds: [], // <-- initially empty array
  filterClassifieds: null,
  loading: true,
};
```

or

```js
const classifieds = useSelector((state) => {
  return state.classifieds.Classifieds ?? []; // <-- provide fallback
});
```

You then use a `useEffect` hook to duplicate the `classifieds` when it updates `filterClassifieds`

```js
const classifieds = useSelector((state) => state.classifieds.Classifieds);

const [filterClassifieds, setFilterClassifieds] = useState(classifieds);

useEffect(() => {
  setFilterClassifieds(classifieds);
}, [classifieds]);
```

But be aware that it is generally considered a React anti-pattern to duplicate state/props locally. My suggestion to correct this would be to use a filter state and compute the derived filtered result inline when rendering. I think this is what the `active` state is.

Example:

```js
const [active, setActive] = useState('Show All');

const classifieds = useSelector((state) => state.classifieds.Classifieds);

// Compute filtered value
const filterClassifieds = classifieds.filter((item) => {
  return active !== "Show All" ? item.category === active : true;
});
 
const handleButton = (name) => {
  if (modal) {
    setModal(false);
  }
  setActiveMoreButtons('');
  setActive(name); // <-- sets filtering value
}
```

If filtering was an "expensive" call you can memoize the result with the `useMemo` hook:

```js
const filterClassifieds = useMemo(() => {
  return classifieds.filter((item) => {
    return active !== "Show All" ? item.category === active : true;
  });
}, [active, classifieds]);
```

***Note:** Keep in mind that a general rule of thumb is that when you have coded a `useState`/`useEffect` combo that you really should use the `useMemo` hook.*

Full code:

```
const buttons = [
  'Show All',
  'Rental',
  'Services',
  'Wanted',
  'Cars',
  'For Sale',
  'More'
];

export const Classifieds = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [active, setActive] = useState('Show All');

  const classifieds = useSelector((state) => state.classifieds.Classifieds);
  const classifiedsLoading = useSelector((state) => state.classifieds.loading);

  const filterClassifieds = classifieds.filter((item) => {
    return active !== "Show All" ? item.category === active : true;
  });
 
  const handleButton = (name) => {
    if (modal) {
      setModal(false);
    }
    setActiveMoreButtons('');
    setActive(name);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getClassifieds());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const transformDate = (datePosted) => {
    const newDate = new Date(datePosted);
    return newDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="section properties">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row properties-box">
            <Table striped hover>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Category</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                  <th>Date Posted</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              {!classifiedsLoading && (
                <tbody>
                  {filterClassifieds?.map((val, ind) => (
                    <tr key={ind}>
                      <td>{val?.category}</td>
                      <td>
                        {val?.heading
                          .split('', 86)
                          .reduce((o, c) => o.length === 85
                            ? `${o}${c}...`
                            : `${o}${c}` , ''
                          )
                        }
                      </td>
                      <td>{transformDate(val?.date)}</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              )}
            </Table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Drew thanks for the answer I have uploaded the full class now to help you understand where I am using filteredClassifieds. It is for function called handleButton. on clicking that button it will filter data and return only the required. currently i tried your approach of not using filteredClassified but it didn't work

Comment: @khemangarg Are you sure you applied the changes correctly? The solutions I suggested all still use the `filterClassifieds` state/value.

Comment: check in the code name will not work in the code snippet that you described because it should come from calling a function

const filterClassifieds = useMemo(() => {
  return classifieds.filter((item) => {
    return active !== "Show All" ? item.category === name : true;
  });
}, [active, classifieds]);

Comment: I think you will need to edit the answer I have modified the code above check that

Comment: @khemangarg Ack, you're right, it should be `active` in the filter callback. I checked and rechecked when posting, still missed that. An IDE would have caught that though, but all we get here is a plain text editor. Sorry for any confusion that may've caused.

Comment: So Here's the result I have tried both the approaches that you told:

first one works but it is not recommended as it is an anti-pattern
second approach does not work because again it will call out the issue that filterClassifieds is empty.

I have also pasted both the approches above in my question please see

Comment: @khemangarg In the second approach `filterClassifieds` is only when `classifieds` is empty. When the `classifieds` state updates this `Classifieds` component should be triggered to rerender and the `filterClassifieds` is computed again. Are you sure your `item.category` values match the `buttons` values, e.g. are `item.category` values in `['Rental', 'Services', 'Wanted', 'Cars', 'For Sale', 'More']`?

Comment: Awesome both the solution works man! but one small hurdle I am pasting the screenshot of that in my question in the end... it shows some warning in the console. Any idea how can i fix that I am using the second approach that you told along with useMemo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256549/discussion-between-kheman-garg-and-drew-reese).

Comment: just posted the screenshot of the console log